# Which NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS for WE8MSWIN1252 Character Set

Tags: character-encoding, oracle11g, database-schema

We have a database where the character set is set to WE8MSWIN1252 which I understand is a single byte character set.

We created a schema and its tables by running a script with the following:

ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR

Could we possibly lose data since we are using VARCHAR2 columns with character semantics while the underlying character set is single byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a single-byte character set like Windows-1252, it is irrelevant whether you are using character or byte semantics.  Each character occupies exactly one byte so it doesn't matter whether a column is declared `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)` or `VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)`.  In either case, up to 10 bytes of storage for up to 10 characters will be allocated.

Since you gain no benefit from changing the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` setting, you ought to keep the setting at the default (`BYTE`) since that is less likely to cause issues with other scripts that you might need to run (such as those from Oracle).

Comment: what if they were not using a single-byte character set?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question.  Multi-byte characters will take up the number of bytes required, which could use more storage than you expect.  If you store a 4-byte character in a varchar2(4) column, you have used all 4 bytes.  If you store a 4-byte character in a varchar2(4 char) column, you have only used 1 character.  Many foreign languages and special characters use 2-byte character sets, so it's best to 'know your data' and make your database column definitions accordingly.  Oracle does NOT recommend changing NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to CHAR because it will affect every new column defined as CHAR or VARCHAR2, possibly including your catalog tables when you do an in-place upgrade.  You can see why this is probably not a good idea.  Other Oracle toolsets and interfaces may present issues as well.